# Issue with using Box SDK on Cocoapods while Google Analytics is included in the same pod file

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics, cocoapods, box

Until few days ago, everything worked fine on my Xcode project where I had both 'box-ios-sdk' and 'Google/Analytics' on my pod file.

But today after doing 'pod update', if 'box-ios-sdk' is on my pod file along with 'Google/Analytics', compiling the project would give me a link error. Taking out 'box-iso-sdk' would solve the issue.

The error is:

ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There are some same/ Duplicate file in your code. find duplicate and remove it.

Comment: It's automatically downloaded by the cocoa pods framework and are required by the pods I mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, Pod haven't duplicate file, But I Say outside of POD have also same duplicate file, That have to remove.

Comment: Dude, like I already said, this error I have confirmed with a blank app as well. I don't have any files on it. Just installed pods on the project and ran it. And if you check the error and the directory of the error, you can see its happening inside the pod directory. Inside that pod directory, there isn't any files that I can modify. Only just a framework file.